# About order of task execution in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have defined two tasks in my app's gradle file for my Android application. There are two flavors of my application and I want these two tasks to run only for one flavor. To achieve this, I am using the following gradle configuration:

```
task A << { ... }

task B << { ... }

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if(task.name.contains('assembleFreeVersion')) {
        task.dependsOn A
        task.dependsOn B
    } 
}
```

My question is this: Will task A always be executed after task B has been executed? If not, what can I do to ensure that without tightly coupling tasks A and B (i.e. I should still be able to run one task without running the other)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer would be no. Dependency does not specify the order. To specify the order you need to use [`mustRunAfter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#mustRunAfter(java.lang.Object...)):

```
task A << { ... }

task B << { ... }

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if(task.name.contains('assembleFreeVersion')) {
        task.dependsOn A
        task.dependsOn B
        B.mustRunAfter A
    } 
}
```